# NSWindow beginSheet:completionHandler With No Response Buttons

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa, nswindow

I understand that `NSApp`'s `beginSheet:modalForWindow` is deprecated for OS X 10.10.  So I need a replacement for it.  The thing is that I only want to show a window sheet with a progress wheel and **no okay or cancel buttons** while some work is under way with `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone`.  Anyway, I have written the following lines of code for Objective-C and Swift.

```
- (void)Backgroundwork :(NSWindow *)window :(NSString *)labelMsg {
    NSRect sheetRect = NSMakeRect(0,0,400,114);
    NSWindow *progSheet = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:sheetRect styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:YES];
    NSView *contentView = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:sheetRect];
    NSProgressIndicator *progInd = [[NSProgressIndicator alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(190,74,20,20)];
    [progInd setStyle:NSProgressIndicatorSpinningStyle];

    NSTextField *messageLabel = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(20,20,240,46)];
    messageLabel.stringValue = labelMsg;
    [messageLabel setBezeled:NO];
    [messageLabel setDrawsBackground:NO];
    [messageLabel setEditable:NO];
    [messageLabel setSelectable:NO];
    [contentView addSubview:messageLabel];
    [contentView addSubview:progInd];
    [progSheet setContentView:contentView];

    [window beginSheet:progSheet completionHandler:^(NSModalResponse returnCode) {
        // some work        
    }];
}

func Backgroundwork(window:NSWindow,labelMsg:String) -> Void {
    let sheetRect:NSRect = NSMakeRect(0,0,400,114)
    let progSheet:NSWindow = NSWindow.init(contentRect:sheetRect, styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask,backing:NSBackingStoreType.Buffered,`defer`:true)
    let contentView:NSView = NSView.init(frame:sheetRect)
    let progInd:NSProgressIndicator = NSProgressIndicator.init(frame:NSMakeRect(190,74,20,20))
    progInd.style = NSProgressIndicatorStyle.SpinningStyle
    let msgLabel:NSTextField = NSTextField.init(frame:NSMakeRect(20,20,240,46))
    msgLabel.stringValue = labelMsg;
    msgLabel.bezeled = false
    msgLabel.drawsBackground = false
    msgLabel.editable = false
    msgLabel.selectable = false
    contentView.addSubview(msgLabel)
    contentView.addSubview(progInd)
    progSheet.contentView = contentView

    window.beginSheet(progSheet) {(NSModalResponse) -> Void in
        // some work  
    }
}
```

If I'm correct, `NSWindow`'s `beginSheet:completionHandler` requires response buttons.  So the application never enters the beginSheet bloc in the code above.  Right?  Or can I still use `beginSheet:completionHandler` without response (okay,cancel) buttons?  Or do I have to use something else other than beginSheet like a modal window that I have to open and close?

Thanks.

---

### Update 1

Maybe, making it a modal window with NSModalSession is the best alternative?

```
let session:NSModalSession = NSApp.beginModalSessionForWindow(progSheet)
```

This approach seems to conform to OS X 10.10.

Comment: Why do you think the sheet requires buttons?

Comment: How could you write `beginSheet:completionHandler` without `NSModalResponse`, then?  That's the question of my topic.

Comment: You don't have to use the return code. How did you dismiss the sheet?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see the point of dismissing the sheet when in fact the application never enters the bloc.

Comment: The block is executed when you dismiss the sheet. I would do `beginSheet; doSomething; endSheet;`. The completion handler is empty.